# Unit testing in Ember.js

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js

Given Ember reached `1.0.0` recently, I wanted to start using it with tests. I'm using Yeoman 1.0 with Karma. I want to unit test models but I'm finding it very difficult to accomplish isolation.

The example I have now is:

```js
describe("Expense", function() {
  return it("has a computed property called `explained`", function() {
    var expense = App.Expense.create({
      name: "My first expense",
      value: 34
    });
    return expect(expense.get("explained")).to.equal("My first expense -- 34");
  });
});
```

As of `1.0.0`, I get the following error:

```
Error: You should not call `create` on a model. Instead, call
`store.createRecord` with the attributes you would like to set.
```

**How should I access store in order to create a model instance?** More ideally, how can I simply spawn models like this without even resorting to the store, is that viable? There's no point in spawning an entire app just to test a model, IMO.

Thank you.

Comment: The only way I can think of is to lookup the store via App.__container__.lookup('store:main'). Perhaps you can also take a look at how they do it in ember-data DS.Model tests

Comment: For those looking for an answer, this hack works. Marking it as solved.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the minimum code that I've used so far for unit testing models.

```
var container, store, expense;

container = new Ember.Container();
container.register('store:main', DS.Store.extend());
container.register('model:expense', App.Expense);
store = container.lookup('store:main');

Ember.run( function() {
  expense = store.createRecord('expense', {
    name: "My first expense",
    value: 34
  });
});
```

Based on the code of the store and [the way models are tested inside Ember Data](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.3/packages/ember-data/tests/unit/model_test.js), I don't think that you can reduce the setup of the test.

Answer (score 2):

According to @sly7_7's commentary, looking for the store inside the app via `App.__container__.lookup('store:main')` works.

Comment: For those kind of things, I always hope to have an advice of a core team member... but after all, this is tests, not production code, so I would think this is good enough

Answer (score 0):

You should use this.get('store').createRecord('expense')

It looks like you're using Ember-Data 1.0.0 beta, which changed the way things work. You should take a look at the migration.md file in the ember-data project.

(Sorry I should have read your question a bit better - I'm having the same issue at the moment and the suggested **container** solution doesn't work for me - causing browsers to crash) :(

Comment: Since writing this, I've discovered that this solution actually *does* work for me, it's just that it needs to be run inside the qunit's test's setup function.